# Android: Arranging apps which widgets do I use: GridLayout / GridView

Tags: android, performance, gridview, grid-layout

I understand the items that are visible to the user will be loaded when using GridView. Does this also applied when using GridLayout?

I currently working on laying out the applications' icon like the applications screen does. When user pressed the icon of the application they are allowed to arrange the icon in an unoccupied space.

At the moment, I don't know which widgets is preferred to use. If GridLayout behave the same as GridView, I would stick with that so no need to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to drag icons to rearrange them I would consider using `GridLayout` with `RecyclerView`. Take a look at [Drag and Swipe with RecyclerView
Part Two: Handles, Grids, and Custom Animations](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.yh8u4yuwr).

If you are unfamiliar with `RecyclerView` and `ItemTouchHelper` then also look at [Part One](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.5yoz1lv5h) first

Comment: Is very nice links , I may need this later for something else. For now, I don't need to use dragging abilities. I saw there is a GridLayoutManager, I do  i find that class?